# php not showing all images

Tags: php, gallery

I a writing a gallery app in php. The images are dynamically displayed through php. 
On each load of the page, not all images are showing. it does this randomly, on each load.

I have not had this problem before, as I am new to php. My previous apps where all in perl, and I had no dynamic image display problems when using that language.

check it here:
http://dev.system-engine.com/dev/exec/pcli.php?R=%27/Paintings%27&cfg=%22fgal%22

all help appreciated.

thank,

Jer A

here is some of the code:

```
function imageThumbLoad($ref) {


$path = FOTOGAL_PORT::$ROOT.$ref;
$path=preg_replace("/\'/","",$path);

$path=preg_replace("/\"/","",$path);

 $path=preg_replace("/\*/"," ",$path);

 $path=preg_replace("/\^/","&",$path);

 $path=preg_replace("/\/([^\/]*)\/\.\./","",$path);



 if(preg_match_all("/\.jpg|\.jpeg/",$path,$tmpmatches))
 {
 header("Content-type: image/jpeg");


  $fh = fopen($path, 'r');
  while (!feof($fh)) {
    $l= fgets($fh, 4096);
    print $l;
  }
  fclose($fh);

 }
```

Comment: A sample of source code would be infinitely more helpful than the resultant output. Try to isolate the particular section of code (do you have an image-loading function, etc.) and post it. Doing so will help get your question answered, or at least provide a direction.

Comment: Make sure it's not a browser issue by testing on alternate browsers, I'd say.

Comment: I dont think it is a browser issue, because Firefox and IE are showing the same issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything shows up just fine here, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> in your browser.

If that doesn't solve try restarting your web server or checking the configuration directives.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved the issue.

use 'fread' instead of 'fgets'

```
 $fh = fopen($path, 'r');

 $contents = fread($fh, filesize($path));

 print $contents;
```